# What is model.trainable_variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have vgg19 model and I want to Fine-Tune.

```
# fine tuning the vgg19 model

# let's take a look to see how many layers are in the base model
print("Number of layers in the base model: ", len(vgg_model.layers))

# fine-tune from this layer onwards
fine_tune_at = 100

# freeze all the layers before the `fine_tune_at` layer
for layer in vgg_model.layers[:fine_tune_at]:
  layer.trainable = False

Number of layers in the base model:  22
```

When summary model

```
Total params: 20,090,177
Trainable params: 65,793
Non-trainable params: 20,024,384
```

```
# compiling the model
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

```
len(model.trainable_variables)

4
```

I wonder what is `len(model.trainable variables) = 4` ???

Can someone explain to me?

Comment: See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/trainable_variables) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_modules) for what trainable variables are in tensorflow in general. The specific variable will depend on your model.

Comment: do `print(model.trainable_variables)` to take a look at your specific variables

Answer (score 0):

- Most models are made of layers. Layers are functions with a known
  mathematical structure that can be reused and have trainable
  variables. Any variable that can be modified during training of the model is known as a trainable variable.
- The distinction between trainable variables and non-trainable variables
  is used to let Optimizers know which variables they can act upon.

  ```
  print("trainable variables:", simple_module.trainable_variables)     
  print("all variables:", simple_module.variables)
  ```

The above code can be used to get all the trainable and non trainable variables in the model. Thank You.